# Windows equivalent of the linux kernel AnyIP feature

Tags: windows, networking, linux-kernel

I have been leveraging the linux kernel's [AnyIP](https://blog.widodh.nl/2016/04/anyip-bind-a-whole-subnet-to-your-linux-machine/) feature to provide me with tens of thousands of addresses without the need to actually alias/assign those IPs and I was hoping the same feature has an equivalent for windows.

On linux I typically do:

```sh
ip link add dummyEth type dummy
ip link set dummyEth up
ip addr add 10.250.0.0/16 dev dummyEth 
ip route add local 10.250.0.0/16 dev dummyEth
```

And that allows me to bind/ping any address for `10.250.0.1` to `10.250.255.254`

Does windows (enterprise) support this or will I be stuck with adding 60,000+ aliases to an interface (assuming windows can even support that many)?